# Can't construct a valid graph URL after uploading to FaceBook via app

Tags: facebook, url, facebook-graph-api

I am uploading an image using the Graph API.  The image is successfully uploaded and I get an id as part of the success response.  I then take the id that is returned, say 3368124406670, and try to to create a URL of the form:

https://graph.facebook.com/3368124406670

This URL will return just the word "false".

I have tried variants such as:

- https://graph.facebook.com/id=3368124406670
- https://graph.facebook.com/3368124406670?access_token={my valid access token}
- https://graph.facebook.com?id=3368124406670

I am yet unable to find a URL that will display the image in the browser window.  What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:

Following Alexander's guidance, I added user_photos permission to the permission list.  Now constructing the graph URL and typing it into a browser gives me the following, and all URLs referenced work except for the link (not sure why - I get a "This content is currently unavailable"):

```
{
   "id": "3372724601672",
  "from": {
      "name": "Mahboud Zabetian",
      "id": "1376000736"
   },
   "name": "Image captured with Lumin",
   "picture": "https://fbcdn-photos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/418881_3372724601672_1376000736_3381246_172283499_s.jpg",
   "source": "https://fbcdn-sphotos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/s720x720/418881_3372724601672_1376000736_3381246_172283499_n.jpg",
   "height": 479,
   "width": 720,
   "images": [
      {
         "width": 2048,
         "height": 1365,
         "source": "https://fbcdn-sphotos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/328625_3372724601672_1376000736_3381246_172283499_o.jpg"
      },
      {
         "width": 720,
         "height": 479,
         "source": "https://fbcdn-sphotos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/s720x720/418881_3372724601672_1376000736_3381246_172283499_n.jpg"
      },
      {
         "width": 180,
         "height": 119,
         "source": "https://fbcdn-photos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/418881_3372724601672_1376000736_3381246_172283499_a.jpg"
      },
      {
         "width": 130,
         "height": 86,
         "source": "https://fbcdn-photos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/418881_3372724601672_1376000736_3381246_172283499_s.jpg"
      },
      {
         "width": 75,
         "height": 49,
         "source": "https://fbcdn-photos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/418881_3372724601672_1376000736_3381246_172283499_t.jpg"
      }
   ],
   "link": "https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=3372724601672&set=a.3242188098341.159612.1376000736&type=1",
   "icon": "https://s-static.ak.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v1/yz/r/StEh3RhPvjk.gif",
   "created_time": "2012-02-20T22:07:38+0000",
   "position": 56,
   "updated_time": "2012-02-20T22:07:40+0000"
}
```

Comment: All three of those should return you an Image object, inside which will be a URL for the .jpg file itself - are you sure it's uploading correctly to your album? Can you see it on facebook.com?

Comment: I can see the image in my album.  I can't access it with these URLs.  I only get "false".

Comment: Is the ID you see on facebook.com the same URL you're checking in the graph API?

Comment: You wrote "except for the link" ... which link?

Comment: The entry tagged with "link".  5th line from the bottom.  This line:  "link": "https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=3372724601672&set=a.3242188098341.159612.1376000736&type=1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://graph.facebook.com/282737675106726?access_token=... 
This should be working. Are you getting user_photos permission?

Comment: I only get "false".  I am typing this URL into a browser, so I am not sure where user_photos permission would come in.  The photo is uploaded into my album, using my app.  I log into my Facebook account, which is the account the picture is in.  I can see the picture in the album, but I can't access it with any of the above URLs.

Comment: For the URL that you posted, I get a false also.

Comment: I haven't givven you permission to access my photo. That's why you get false.
In your application you need to ask user_photos permissions together with the basic permissions. Then apply the received access token to the url you posted.